# Comparing strings not working using contains or equals methods

Tags: string, vb.net, comparison

I have a bizarre situation because it is seemingly simple. I am doing a comparison of text from two sources to see if they match.

```vb
Source1.ToUpper.Contains(Source2.ToUpper)
```

Checking the values of each

```vb
Source1 = "Test"
Source2 = "Test"
```

IF i do this:

```vb
Source1 = Source2
```

> False

I then **copied and pasted** the results from the variables output in the formula below and got **false** result

```vb
"Test".ToUpper.Contains("Test.ToUpper)
```

But when I manually typed in the word "Test" in the formula...."True"!  Like it should be. I can't figure this out!

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Something different is happening here. Check if your test string contains some invisible character

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `trim`?

```
If Source1.trim = Source2.Trim Then
     Return TRUE
Else
     Return FALSE
End If
```

Comment: This can be simplified by removing the If/Else all together since the result of the comparison is a boolean: `Return Source1.Trim() = Source2.Trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce.

```
    'Source1="Test" Source2="Test"
    Dim Source1 As String = "Test"
    Dim Source2 As String = "Test"
    If Source1 = Source2 Then Stop 'stopped here DUH
```

**To verify there aren't invisible characters**

```
    'verify each character
    For Each c As Char In Source1
        Debug.Write(AscW(c))
        Debug.Write(" ")
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    For Each c As Char In Source2
        Debug.Write(AscW(c))
        Debug.Write(" ")
    Next
```